# Cannot find index of a character in java string

Tags: java

I found a very strange problem in my java program. I want find indices of all pipe in my string and save them into 5 variables, but result is not right. Here is my program:

```
public class forTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String tmp = "A|B|C|D|E|F|";
        int count = 0;
        int start = 0;
        int start1 = 0;
        int start2 = 0;
        int start3 = 0;
        int start4 = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < tmp.length(); i++){
            if(tmp.substring(i, i+1).equals("|")){
                count = count + 1;
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            if(count == 1){
                start = i;
            }
            if(count == 2){
                start1 = i;
            }
            if(count == 3){
                start2 = i;
            }
            if(count == 4){
                start3 = i;
            }
            if(count == 5){
                start4 = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(start + "|" +start1 + "|" +start2
                                 + "|" +start3 + "|" +start4);
    }
```

Output:

```
Result is 1

1 3 5 7 9 11

2|4|6|8|10
```

Comment: I can't really tell what the question is from this.

Comment: I think result should be 1 3 5 7 9

Comment: `tmp.substring(i, i+1).equals("|")` should be `tmp.charAt(i) == '|'`.

Comment: There are 6 pipe symbols, why would you expect only 5 indices?

Comment: because I only care about first 5. They should be 1 3 5 7 9, while result is 2 4 6 8 10.

Comment: You haven't specifically ignored the 6th pipe symbol, so it is going to be printed.

Comment: I ignored.... 5 variables are start, start1, start2, start3, start4, so it is NOT going to be printed.

Comment: @Frankie People are getting confused about your *debug* print statement inside the loop, since that *will* print all `|` positions. Your question is not clear on the fact that you're referring to the final print statement only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you iterate, the first `|` will increment `count` to `1`, and set `start = 1`, but on next iteration when you're positioned on the `B`, the count is still 1, and `start` is updated to `2`.

**Debugging** with a breakpoint on `start = i;` would have let you see this for yourself!

Solution: Move all the `if` statements inside the first one.

Also, `tmp.substring(i, i+1).equals("|")` should be `tmp.charAt(i) == '|'`, and use `else if`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length(); i++) {
    if (tmp.charAt(i) == '|') {
        count = count + 1;
        System.out.println(i);
        if (count == 1) {
            start = i;
        } else if (count == 2) {
            start1 = i;
        } else if (count == 3) {
            start2 = i;
        } else if (count == 4) {
            start3 = i;
        } else if (count == 5) {
            start4 = i;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Alternate solutions**

A shorter piece of code to get the same result can be done using a regular expression:

```
String tmp = "A|B|C|D|E|F|";
String regex = "(\\|).*?(\\|).*?(\\|).*?(\\|).*?(\\|)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(tmp);
if (m.find()) {
    int start  = m.start(1);
    int start1 = m.start(2);
    int start2 = m.start(3);
    int start3 = m.start(4);
    int start4 = m.start(5);
    System.out.println(start + "|" +start1 + "|" +start2 + "|" +start3 + "|" +start4);
}
```

Or if you don't like that, you could use an array:

```
String tmp = "A|B|C|D|E|F|";
int count = 0;
int[] start = new int[5];
for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length(); i++)
    if (tmp.charAt(i) == '|' && count < start.length)
        start[count++] = i;
System.out.println(start[0] + "|" +start[1] + "|" +start[2] + "|" +start[3] + "|" +start[4]);
```

*Output (from both)*

```
1|3|5|7|9
```

Comment: get it! Thank you very much! Only one question, why should I use tmp.charAt(i) rather than tmp.substring(i, i+1)? I can get correct result by using tmp.substring(i, i+1).